# Compile CSProj in Visual Studio with /CLR:Safe? Fatal Error LNK1302: only support linking safe .netmodules

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-c++, .net-3.5, c++-cli

So I am having an issue converting an opensource project (SQLite) to use a different build system and now I'm having trouble linking projects. Essentially I have a VCProj file that has a definition like this:

```
<Tool
   Name="VCLinkerTool"
   AdditionalOptions="/ASSEMBLYRESOURCE:..\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteCommand.bmp,System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteCommand.bmp&#x0D;&#x0A;/ASSEMBLYRESOURCE:..\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteConnection.bmp,System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteConnection.bmp&#x0D;&#x0A;/ASSEMBLYRESOURCE:..\System.Data.SQLite\SQLiteDataAdapter.bmp,System.Data.SQLite.SQLiteDataAdapter.bmp"
   AdditionalDependencies="..\System.Data.SQLite\bin\System.Data.SQLite.netmodule"
   OutputFile="..\bin\System.Data.SQLite.DLL"
   GenerateManifest="false"
   IgnoreDefaultLibraryNames=""
   ModuleDefinitionFile="src\sqlite3.def"
   EmbedManagedResourceFile=""
   DelayLoadDLLs="advapi32.dll"
   RandomizedBaseAddress="1"
   DataExecutionPrevention="0"
   ImportLibrary=""
   KeyFile="..\System.Data.SQLite\System.Data.SQLite.snk"
   CLRUnmanagedCodeCheck="true"
/>
```

And I am unable to properly link the System.Data.SQLite.netmodule due to the following error:

> Linking...
>   4>..\System.Data.SQLite\bin\System.Data.SQLite.netmodule : fatal error LNK1302: only support  linking safe .netmodules; unable to link pure .netmodule

And the System.Data.SQLite.netmodule is generated from a C#/.NET project. How is it I can force it to compile with the `/clr:safe` option since according to [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9x035d1s%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) this is the way to fix the issue. The problem is is that I don't know how to compile it with `/clr:safe`. How is it I can do that in the csproj file or in visual studio somewhere? If I am off base in my attempts to fix this please let me know a better way.

**UPDATE**:
So I have determined the issue but I'm not sure why it is an issue. So the interop project (the C project which compiles the sqlite code and links) uses the VCLinkerTool to link to the System.Data.SQLite.netmodule. There is then a C# project that creates the System.Data.SQLite.netmodule using the following command (Anything in {} was added to reduce length):

`C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework\v3.5\Csc.exe /noconfig /unsafe- /nowarn:1701,1702 /platform:AnyCPU /errorreport:prompt /doc:..\bin\System.Data.SQLite.XML {DLL REFEERENCFES /debug- /filealign:512 /optimize+ /out:obj\Release\System.Data.SQLite.netmodule {RESOURCES AND CS FILES}`

The problem is with the `/platform:AnyCPU`. In my build it is `/platform:x86` and for some reason this causes issues when linking and I'm not sure why but this is what I have narrowed it down to since I can change it to AnyCPU and it will build and link properly. Any insight on this is appreciated.

Comment: Why not compile with `/clr:pure` instead?

Comment: @ildjarn: Best guess is that he wants to deploy to something like the Windows Phone, which allows only safe code.

Comment: How can `System.Data.SQLite.netmodule` be generated from a C# project when SQLite is a C/C++ database? AFAIK it is compiled with C++/CLI using /clr:pure which is why you get the error message. You can't use SQLite in an environment that requires verifiable code, e.g. WP7

Comment: @adrianm: I agree with what you say except for the fact that the System.Data.SQLite project is able to accomplish this. And System.Data.SQLite is an ADO.NET adapter so the System.Data.SQLite.netmodule is a generated from the C# code in the project.

Comment: It is not that simple for the linker to figure out whether an assembly is pure vs safe.  The CLR header in the assembly contains not enough information.  Surely it is using the 32BIT flag to conclude that there's something amiss with it, safe code never has a platform dependency.  The default for C# projects has changed in VS2010, use Project + Properties, Build tab, Platform target setting to go back to AnyCPU.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok so I finally narrowed down what the issue was and maybe someone can spread some more light onto why that is but I have a rough idea why. Basically you can't have the VCLinkerTool link to .netmodules that were created targetting the `/platform:x86` (and I assume any other variant that isn't `AnyCpu`. I would assume this has to do with the way that the linking occurs internally  when linking the mixed mode dll with a .netmodule. So it looks like for this to work you have to have your C# project compiled with `/platorm:AnyCpu`.

Answer (score 0):

[This](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/k8d11d4s.aspx) may be what you are looking for:

To set this compiler option in Visual Studio

1.
In Solution Explorer, right-click the project name, and then click Properties to open the project Property Pages dialog box.

2.
Select the Configuration Properties folder.

3.
On the General property page, modify the Common Language Runtime support property.

Note

When /clr is enabled in the Property Pages dialog box, compiler option properties that are not compatible with /clr are also adjusted, as required. For example, if /RTC is set and then /clr is enabled, /RTC will be turned off.

Also, when you debug a /clr application, set the Debugger Type property to Mixed or Managed only. For more information, see Project Settings for a C++ Debug Configuration.

For information about how the create a module, see /NOASSEMBLY (Create a MSIL Module).

Comment: The problem is that it is complaining that the module from C# needs to be compiled with those options and C# does not have those menus

Comment: As it turns out this didn't appear to be an issue. It looks like Microsoft only lists out how to fix this when working with C projects and not with .netmodule created from C#. I'm surprised this isn't documented anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

You would have to edit the CSProj to not use features that cause the code to no longer be `safe`. These are easy to spot -- anywhere where you're using <s>P/Invoke, or anywhere where there's</s> an `unsafe` code block, that code is not safe. If any of the code in your assembly is unsafe, the whole assembly gets marked as unsafe.

If you remove the unsafe code the resultant assembly will automatically be safe.

(In the case of SQLite I believe this will be impossible, because SQLite is a C library, which cannot be compiled as `safe`)

Comment: IIRC, P/Invoke generates verifiable IL and is consequently irrelevant here; `unsafe` is C#'s only mechanism for generating unverifiable IL.

Comment: Yeah but this works fine with the original source code. Only when I change it over and I'm not sure what I'm missing since the CSProj files are essentially the same